# AOE Scheduler 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento, cpanel, internal-server-error, cron-task

I´m trying to set up AOE Scheduler command on my Godaddy´s cPanel but I get a 500 Internal Server Error.
AOE Scheduler´s instructions say I should add these two command lines:

```
* * * * * ! test -e /home/gimbals/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/gimbals/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
* * * * * ! test -e /home/gimbals/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/gimbals/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default
```

I´ve done so:
[cPanel screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLZEn.png)
...but I get this error by email:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Have you solved this problem and if yes, how?